# Message "Unable to unprotect message.State" when scaling IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

When running a single instance of IdentityServer4, we can login with another identity provider succesfully. As soon as we create several instances of IdentityServer4, the same process fails after the user authenticated if the result is handled by a different server.

The message "Unable to unprotect message.State" is written to the logs even though ASP.NET Core DataProtection API is configured correctly to run in a multi server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to ASP.NET Core DataProtection, some components of IdentityServer4 rely on ASP.NET Core distributed caching. In our case, the following call registered a component that relies on `IDistributedCache`:

```
services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();
```

In the default implementation, an in-memory-cache is used which leads to the problem. 
After removing the line, IdentityServer4 works in the multi server deployment.

An alternative would be to configure distributed caching to work in a multi-server environment as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed).